# Excel 2003: max length dropdown list

Tags: excel

I have a simple question, but searching on the internet didn't help me (maybe my brains are not working as they should... :S).
I have a dropdown list in Excel 2003, which I fill via VBA script. Now I get errors, when the size of the list is to big. In know there is a limit to the number of characters in a list.

At first I didn't had the error, when I was working in Excel 2007. But I needed to change to 2003. Before going further, defining a functional solution, I would like to know what the limitation is, **max number of characters**, of the **dropdown list** in **Excel 2003**??

Note: if found [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx) MS website, but I don't see what I'm looking for...

Comment: is the list on a form or in a sheet? How long is the list you are trying to add? Maybe you code is problematic. How are you adding to the list?

Comment: @datatoo: it is a little bit nasty. It is a dynamic list. I create an array with the values needed (based on different rules). Then I concatenate the array to a string with separators (',' in my Excel version), which I add to the 'validation' of the cell. (cell.Validation ... Formula1:=list... >> where 'list' is the concatenated string). The length of the list is not known, but most of the times it fails (list entries are about 30 characters long, 10+ list entries). There is probably a maximum for this, in characters. How to solve? Do I need to refer to a (dummy) range with the values instead?

Comment: when you step through have you tried viewing the string being created from the array? It may be your code is not doing that correctly. Any sample? Perhaps test by writing the string to a range temporarily to check. You could just build the string directly counting delimiters to know the size of the list. And @Sean Chesire seems to have the specs for this correct

Comment: Code was correct, but just too long...fixed it using an array for the list. Unfortunately this had to be on the same worksheet, as excel 2003 does not allow validation list to be on another sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For excel 2003, the limits I can find are per [Microsoft](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-remove-a-drop-down-list-HP005202215.aspx): The maximum number of entries that you can have in a drop-down list is 32,767.
There also seems to be  limit of 256 characters per item.

Comment: And what about the length of the list, if you use the field in the validation area of the cell? (just typing in the list entries, with a separator)